# Qt - Copying a QTableWidget's Data and Paste it in Another QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, copy, paste, qtablewidget

I asked a question very similar to this  but the person who responded gave a small amount of help and I couldn't solve my problem. I thought I would re-ask the question since no-one else has responded to my problem. I would like to know how to copy a QTableWidget's Data from one window to another QTableWidget on a different window.

So for example, I would type into "TableWidget1", then with the click of a button, It copies the data from "TableWidget1" and pastes it in "TableWidget2" on a different window.  I have code below which I tried using and when I compiled the program, it worked fine until the copy and paste button was clicked, then it would just crash.

Here is the code (there is a lot, sorry):

tablemainwindow1.h:

```
#ifndef TABLEMAINWINDOW1_H
#define TABLEMAINWINDOW1_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "tabledialougewindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class TableMainWindow1;
}

class TableMainWindow1 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TableMainWindow1(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~TableMainWindow1();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::TableMainWindow1 *ui;
    TableDialougeWindow *tbl2;
};

#endif // TABLEMAINWINDOW1_H
```

tablemainwindow1.cpp:

```
#include "tablemainwindow1.h"
#include "ui_tablemainwindow1.h"

TableMainWindow1::TableMainWindow1(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TableMainWindow1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(3);
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(3);
}

TableMainWindow1::~TableMainWindow1()
{
    delete ui;
}


void TableMainWindow1::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    tbl2 = new TableDialougeWindow(this);
    tbl2->show();
}
```

tabledialougewindow.h:

```
#ifndef TABLEDIALOUGEWINDOW_H
#define TABLEDIALOUGEWINDOW_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class TableDialougeWindow;
}

class TableDialougeWindow : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TableDialougeWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~TableDialougeWindow();

private slots:
    void on_buttonBox_accepted();

private:
    Ui::TableDialougeWindow *ui;
};

#endif // TABLEDIALOUGEWINDOW_H
```

tabledialougewindow.cpp:

```
#include "tabledialougewindow.h"
#include "ui_tabledialougewindow.h"
#include "tablemainwindow1.h"
#include "ui_tablemainwindow1.h"

int Rows = 3;
int Columns = 3;
Ui::TableMainWindow1 *mainui;
TableDialougeWindow::TableDialougeWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TableDialougeWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(Rows);
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(Columns);
}

TableDialougeWindow::~TableDialougeWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void TableDialougeWindow::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    for(int i = 0;i<Columns;++i){
        for(int j = 0;j<Rows;++j){
            QTableWidgetItem *celltxt = ui->tableWidget->item(j,i);
            QTableWidgetItem *celltxt2 =new QTableWidgetItem(*celltxt);
            mainui->tableWidget->setItem(j,i,celltxt2);
        }
    }
    accept();
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Could you please add some additional information: 1. Does the crash occur in the *on_buttonBox_accepted()* method? 2. If so, are the *mainui* and *tableWidget* pointers valid?

Comment: yes it crashes on the accepted method, also, im pretty sure the mainui and tableWidget pointers are valid. (however I might be wrong, how should I validate them?).

Comment: For example, put this at the very beginnig of the *on_buttonBox_accepted()*: `qDebug() << mainui->tableWidget->rowCount();` and `qDebug() << mainui->tableWidget->columnCount();` What does it print the to console? Or does it crash also on those lines?

Comment: adding in these two lines produced errors, instead i ran the program in debug mode, and when clicking on the accepted() method, i got a sigsegv error, segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

Try launching the application in debugger and checking where exactly it crashes.

I see that you set row count and column count, but you never create the actual items. AFAIK `QTableWidget` does not create the items for you. Could it be that this call simply returns `nullptr`?

```
QTableWidgetItem *celltxt = ui->tableWidget->item(j,i);
```

Comment: when running in debug mode i got a sigsegv error. i presume this means null pointer?

Comment: Have a look in the call stack window. It should show in which file/line of your code the problem occurs

Comment: line 29 on dialougewindow.

Comment: this line:QTableWidgetItem *celltxt2 =new QTableWidgetItem(*celltxt);

Comment: It suggest that I am correct: all items are nullptr. The application crashes when you try to de-reference a null pointer. Try creating new `QTableWidgetItem`s and adding them to your cells.

Comment: ok, how should I do this? cause i sort of know what you mean but not to sure on what to do.

Comment: Insert new items in a loop. Here is how to use `QTableWidget`: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Use_QTableWidget

Comment: Create new `QTableWidgetItem` in a loop, for each cell that you have. Use that link as reference

Comment: okay i did this:
    QTableWidgetItem *newitem = new QTableWidgetItem("2");
    mainui->tableWidget->setitem(i,j,newitem);

and it still comes up with a sigsegv error.

Comment: `Ui::TableMainWindow1 *mainui;`, do you initialize it somehow?

Comment: isnt it initalised in  the mainwindow? where it says "ui (new Ui::TableMainWindow1"

Comment: Yes, but the pointer in tabledialougewindow.cpp is not initialized

Comment: so what? i put in the line Ui::TableMainWindow1 *mainui = new Ui::MainWindow; is this what you are on about?

Comment: " i presume this means null pointer?" Don't presume. You can *check* if the pointer is null!

Comment: im sorry, im not the best at qt, as you may know, so please elaborate on what you say, give me an example or something, thank you.